# Simplify the following expressions in (1) sum of products and (2) products of sum :

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, logic, boolean-algebra

a) x'z' + y'z'+ yz' + xy

b) (A'+B'+D')(A+B'+C')(A'+B+D')(B+C'+D')

I can't find a solution!

Comment: Is this calculus or Boolean algebra? It can't really be both (and can't seem to be linear algebra at all).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using the notation in a boolean algebra it appears you could simplify this by grouping or expanding:

a) $x'z'+y'z'+yz'+xy = (x'+y'+y)z' +xy $

b) $(A'+B'+D')(A+B'+C')(A'+B+D')(B+C'+D')=(A'+B'+D')(A'+B+D')(A+B'+C')(B+C'+D')=(A'+D')(A+B'+C')(B+C'+D')$

I'll leave the rest for you to reason about.